# How to insert into multiple tables from a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following code that inserts data into a column however its not loading into the correct columns.what do you think is wrong?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTESt]  
AS

DECLARE @Report TABLE (
   c1 int, c2 int, c3 int, c4 int, c5 int  
)


INSERT INTO @Report  (c1)
SELECT mass as c1 FROM other_sales
WHERE id='17501' order by mass

INSERT INTO @Report (c2)
SELECT mass as c2  FROM other_sales
WHERE id='17154' order by mass 


INSERT INTO @Report  (c3)
SELECT mass FROM other_sales
WHERE id='17156' order by mass


INSERT INTO @Report  (c4)
SELECT mass FROM other_sales
WHERE id='17500' order by mass


INSERT INTO @Report  (c5)
SELECT mass FROM other_sales
WHERE id='17501' order by mass
```

it needs to go into separate columns based on its condition. Should I structure it differently?

Comment: What do you mean it's not loading into the correct columns? Do all these select queries (`SELECT mass FROM other_sales
WHERE id='17501' order by mass`) always return a single value?

Comment: i want it to appear in one line

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE 
      @Report TABLE (

c1 int ,
c2 int ,
c3 int ,
c4 int , 
c5 int

      )

DECLARE @_C1 INT
DECLARE @_C2 INT
DECLARE @_C3 INT
DECLARE @_C4 INT
DECLARE @_C5 INT

SELECT @_C1 = mass FROM other_sales
WHERE id='17501' order by mass

SELECT @_C2 = mass  FROM other_sales
WHERE id='17154' order by mass 

SELECT @_C3 = mass other_sales
WHERE id='17156' order by mass

SELECT @_C4 = mass other_sales
WHERE id='17500' order by mass

SELECT @_C5 = mass other_sales
WHERE id='17501' order by mass

INSERT INTO @Report
        ( c1, c2, c3, c4 , c5 )
VALUES  ( @_C1, -- c1 - int
          @_C2, -- c2 - int
          @_C3, -- c3 - int
          @_C4,  -- c4 - int
          @_C5  -- c5 - int
          )
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all the `select` statements returnsingle values, you could try a single statement as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTESt]  
AS
--......
DECLARE @Report TABLE (c1 int, c2 int, c3 int, c4 int, c5 int )

INSERT INTO @Report  (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5) values (
(SELECT mass FROM other_sales WHERE id='17501'),
(SELECT mass FROM other_sales WHERE id='17154'),
(SELECT mass FROM other_sales WHERE id='17156'),
(SELECT mass FROM other_sales WHERE id='17500'),
(SELECT mass FROM other_sales WHERE id='17501') ) 
--....
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the comma after your last column declaration

```
DECLARE 
      @Report TABLE (

c1 int ,
c2 int ,
c3 int ,
c4 int 

      )
```

Comment: yeah sorry typo error when i was adding it in here but thats not the problem

Comment: Lol ok, no worries, what's the problem though? Do you want these values to appear on a single line, as opposed to multiple lines?

Comment: yeah! thats it,i want it to appear in line,but right now its going all over the place